# Can I give different permissions in a private git repository?

Tags: github

I recently created a private git repository for a project with my friends but I don't want all of them to be collaborators. Can I give some of them the ability to only create pull requests and not merge them?

Answer (score 2):

You could have used [protected branches](https://help.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/about-protected-branches), but they are only available with private repositories for GitHub pro, not GitHub free.

One workaround is simply to create a second private repository for your friends: thy can push to it, and make pull requests to your private repository from there.